# compile error invalid outside procedure

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a table in my Access database where I keep track of my jobs. I have a form based on a query based on this table. In my table there is a field called `[file_path]`. This is a field that controls a web browser on my form.

I would like this field `[File_path]`to be updated when I update my field `[customer_Id]` on the form. It should be updated to reflect the customer name together with the file path e.g. `C:\Users\Windows8\Documents\Projects\Doe John`.

How do I pull the `[Customers]![Last_Name]` and `[Customers]![first_name]` into my string in field `[file_path]`?

I think that I have to use VBA code, but not sure how. I have started with this:

```
Private Sub Customer_AfterUpdate()
Me.File_path = Me.Last_Name
End Sub
```

I know that this is a feeble beginning. Does someone know how to help me? Please tell me if my question is not clear.

Beside all this the above code is returning Invalid outside procedure in `Private Sub Customer_AfterUpdate()`. Why?

Comment: Me.File_path = Me.Last_Name & " " & me.First_name. in your form you should have 3 fields with this names.

Comment: Ok I'm new here. I know that a comment is not the right place to put this. (or is it?)

Comment: Now I get `invalid outside procedure` with this

Comment: Private Sub Customer_AfterUpdate()

    Me.File_path = Me.Last_Name & " " & Me.First_Name
    End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Me` refers to the form. You are correct that using `Me` is best practice (speed, ease of coding, etc.), but when I was starting out or even now in a complicated application I like to write it out, because that reminds me not to make little mistakes like this. Or, maybe your memory is better than mine, in which case ignore and read on.

[file_path] is in the table, so you need to access it in the table. Your code looks for it in the form, and realizes that it isn't inside `Me`, and throws this error.

I am going to give you a line of code below that should be a good starting point for you, but I think you may need to examine your calling event. `AfterUpdate` is cool, because it just seems to happen automatically, but I don't think you want your field updated every single time anything in the whole "Customer" form is updated. If there is a specific textbox that is always updated last (last_name?), you could try that one instead, but I would be nervous about trying to remember to always make sure that was the last one that I updated... I mean, if one day I accidentally did the name before the customer_id, I would have some serious confusion on my hands later on. Might I suggest a command button, and using the `Click` event instead?

No matter what event you end up using, you really only need one line of code inside your event. There are plenty of ways of doing this. Might I suggest something along the lines of `CurrentDb.Execute "update " & myAwesomeTableNameHere & " set file_path='"C:\Users\Windows8\Documents\Projects\" & forms("customers").controls("last_name").text & " " & forms("customers").controls("first_name").text & "' where customer_id='" & forms("customers").controls("customer_id").text & "'"`

Now, a caution: data is precious, and beautiful. The names of the people who pay you are even more so. Changing data in a pre-populated table by free-typing into a textbox on a form sounds like disaster waiting to happen to me. If it were me, I would either 1)make backups very often (easist), or 2)validate your entries multiple ways before writing anything to the table.